# Call function in running Linux process using gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb

I have a running Linux process that is stuck on poll(). It has some data in a buffer, but this buffer is not yet written to disk. Ordinarily I'd kill the process which would cause it to  flush the buffer and and exit.

However, in this case the file it's writing to has been deleted from the file system, so I need the process to write the buffer before it exits, while the inode is still reachable via /proc//fd/

Is it possible to "kick" the process out of the poll() call and single step it until it has flushed the buffer to disk using GDB?

(For the curious, the source code is here: http://sourcecodebrowser.com/alsa-utils/1.0.15/arecordmidi_8c_source.html)

Comment: What use is writing to the deleted file given that it will disappear completely as soon as the program closes its handle?  Is the data you're trying to preserve in the memory buffers or in the deleted file?

Comment: There is a reference to the deleted file in the /proc filesystem since the process is still running. Therefore, if I manage to get the process to write the data, I can copy it out before the process ends (and the file is truly lost).

Comment: Signals tend to wake up processes in system calls

Comment: OK, so the next question becomes, how to wake it up, but make sure it doesn't exit?

Comment: If you've got a debugger attached, that shouldn't be very hard, just put a breakpoint before it closes the file. (you probably also want to `call fflush(...` from the debugger so the contents are written completely before you copy the contents out.) Also, I'll note the code you have should respond to `SIGINT`, which you can trigger from gdb.

Comment: OK, the main problem is that the executable doesn't have any debug symbols. I think I will get a core dump and try to get the buffer out of there somehow.

Comment: You could probably still break on a library function (`fclose()` being a good candidate.)